# A pair of jeans vs tight jeans or blue jeans (without a pair) etc

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, british-english

When can we use *jeans* without *a pair of* in English?

I read the following in a novel:

> She had on **tight jeans** with a pair of pink heels.

Is this proper usage?

Or should the writer have used the following?

> She had on **a pair of tight jeans** with a pair of pink heels.

She is an American writer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True. *A pair of jeans* is commonly used to mean one piece. But then I guess the author avoided it as *a pair of...* is already following. The sentence wouldn't have looked natural using *a pair of...* two times in that short sentence.

Authors do use *jeans* to mean *a pair of jeans*. There are some instances on the newspapers as well. Here is a piece from the [DailyMail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2641935/One-Direction-risk-U-S-ban-shocking-joint-video-weeks-sell-39-date-American-tour.html)

> Louis adopts a faux serious tone as he focuses on Zayn who sits beside him wearing **jeans** and a Bob Marley T-shirt, 'Zayn takes his job very seriously. He makes sure he goes through a two hour intense warm-up before every show. Just to get himself in the zone for the show.

Another example from [OxfordDictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jeans?q=jeans)

> He was wearing blue denim **jeans,** a white shirt with blue stripes in a criss-cross pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  "pair of" is mostly optional but frequently used when the speaker is referring to a specific piece of clothing.

I this case however, I think the author omitted the first "pair of" to avoid having two instances of "pair of" so close together which tends to sound a little clunky.  The second may have been kept for the alliteration between "pair" and "pink".